# Zebra Printer Setup Time Zones (EST)

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zebra-ui-framework

Am printing a label using zebra printer (model: ZT411) thru zpl file. I managed to print the label correctly, however time stamp is printed incorrectly. I want the time stamp to be printed in EST time zone. Am not sure at what level i need to change the time zone setting (Zerver/ZPL/printer).

Please advise.

Thank you,
Ramesh

Provide solution to the above issues.